# Orchard CMS 301 redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, http-status-code-301, orchardcms-1.6

I was wondering which is the best place to hook 301 Url redirection codes in Orchard CMS 1.6?
Any sample code or idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Cant you just use the Rewrite Rules module on the gallery? http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.Contrib.RewriteRules

Comment: That module actually does the job by modifying the .htaccess file. Which can be done without the module too.
Is there anyway we can write some custom code? In that case we can have our own redirection logic.

Comment: +1. @Rahat, look at the code for that module. It lets you create rules in the .htaccess *format*, not by editing a .htaccess file (AFAIK IIS only supports .htaccess with third party extensions). The module Hazza posted provides a great example of how you could intercept requests and do a 301 redirect.

Comment: This being said, the most efficient redirects are done with IIS's URL rewrite feature. It requires modifying web.config, but it will be the fastest by far.

Comment: Your link is dead now.

Comment: @JuannStrauss fixed